# Recommendations for editing same file on different machines

Tags: synchronization, settings, deployment, yaml

Our Rails app is scaled at multiple machines, from time to time, we need to change settings at `production.yml` , right now we have to ssh into each server and do the editing at each machine individually.

What's the right way to handle this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration management systems like [Puppet](https://puppet.com/) and [Chef](https://www.chef.io/) are made for this exact purpose.

If you don't want to use them, you can use a script to SCP the file to the server:

```
while read host; do
    scp -i yourKey production.yml user@$host:/destination/production.yml
    # Add an ssh command here if you need to restart any services
done <  hosts.txt;
```

Comment: currently we are not using those tools, wouldn't this approach involve full deployment cycle ? we only need this particular sync

Comment: Not necessarily, there's nothing wrong with using them to deploy files outside of the development cycle. Although they might be overkill for something small like this. I've edited my answer

Comment: I would consider using one of these tools if I were you. It makes it much easier to manage multiple machines.

Comment: If there are any chances that those files will be changed by someone else after you modify them , thus causing a configuration drift , I would suggest going with @Farhan.K's suggestion as Puppet and Chef will check periodically if there has been any change to the file and if so , change it to what you define . If not , Puppet and Chef could have an overhead since they are agent based , and in this case I would strongly recommend using Ansible which is agentless and uses SSH to connect to managed hosts. You could manage one file and push it to managed hosts. good luck

Comment: using `while read; do .. done < hosts.txt` is horrible; eg. it will ignore the last line of `hosts.txt` if not terminated by a linefeed. And `read` has a lot of other nasty problems. Even `for host in $(cat hosts.txt)` was better. Try `xargs -IHOST <hosts.txt scp ... user@HOST:/...` instead (if `hosts.txt` has one host per line).

Comment: @pizdelect it is not horrible, in fact it is recommended practice and The Correct Way® to read multiple lines from a file. What is horrible is the `for line in $(cat file)` construct which can fail very easily. See [bash pitfall #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Note that all files should be terminated by a newline, if you have files that don't, then that's a whole different problem, but that's not an issue with `read`.

Comment: who's recommending that? either the file contains just hostnames, and `$(cat ...)` is better, or it's containing all kind of stuff, and `read` will crap out just as bad as `$(cat ...)` after reading the junk with puny buffers or even byte-by-byte. (you're not even using `read -r`, for God's sake).

Comment: @pizdelect let's not do this in the comments. I'm happy to discuss it in [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) or you can post a new question.

Comment: @terdon I don't see what could be discussed, since you're ignoring any technical arguments (the fact that `read` is not able to handle files that don't end in LF, that it's doing a syscall for each byte when reading from a pipe, that there's no telling how it will react to signals, etc, etc). I'm not interested in any cargo cult/appeal to authority/bandwaggon arguments or made up rules (eg. that all files "should" be terminated by a newline).

Comment: @pizdelect quite the contrary, I would love to discuss the technical points. I might even learn something! Just not in the comments. I think you're wrong for technical reasons, nothing else, but this isn't the place for the discussion. Please do ping me in chat though, or post a question about this (you can also answer it) so we can discuss without cluttering up the site or bothering the poor OP here.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use rsync instead of scp. Advantages of rsync :

First, it will check whether any changes are  there  or not  in source file when compared with file in destination. Only if there is a change then it will transfer so it will take less time and be faster when compared with `scp.`

```
while read host
do
    rsync -avzh production.yml userid@$host:/destination_location/production.yml
done < hosts.txt
```

Comment: using `while read; do ... done < hosts.txt` is horrible -- same comment as [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497459/recommendations-for-editing-same-file-on-different-machines/497460#comment916664_497460). Also @terdon.

Comment: @pizdelect no, it isn't. It is the best and safest way to read lines from a file. The absolute safest is `while IFS= read -r var; do...`, but this is not needed here. IN any case, using a `while read` loop instead of something truly awful such as `for line in $(cat file)` is both standard and the best practice recommended pretty much everywhere. Also see [1](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/24278), [2](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), [3](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/9496), [4](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766), [5](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697).